# Python "or" statement syntax not functioning?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python programming, anyway this is a small section from a larger piece of code. Which seems to be causing issues:

```
command = input("Command: ")

while command != ("Exit lift" or "Up" or "Down" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "Cycle"):
    print("Error: Command entered doesn't match the 'Commands' list, or isn't a possible command at this time! Please try again...")
    command = input("Command: ")

print ("Works")
```

Basically, I test the commands, and it only picks-up on the "Exit lift" command, and "Up", "Down", "1"...etc. won't work.

Any suggestions? beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
while command != ("Exit lift" or "Up" or "Down" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "Cycle"):
```

you should use

```
while not command in ("Exit lift", "Up", "Down", "1", "2", "3", "Cycle"):
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer :)

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful and simple. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

`("Exit lift" or "Up" or "Down" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "Cycle")` is evaluated to `'Exit lift'`.

```
>>> ("Exit lift" or "Up" or "Down" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "Cycle")
'Exit lift'
```

So `command != ("Exit lift" or "Up" or "Down" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "Cycle"):` is equivalent to `command != ("Exit lift")`.

Use `not in` with sequence:

```
while command not in ("Exit lift", "Up", "Down", "1", "2", "3", "Cycle"):
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array, and use the `in` word

```
allowed = ["Exit lift", "Up", "Down", "1", "2", "3", "Cycle"]

while command not in allowed:
    print "not allowed!"

print "works"
```